# 500 ошибка при отправке формы интернет-магазин

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, интернет-магазин

Есть форма, при нажатии отправить выдает 500 ошибку, хотя заказ обрабатывается и отображается в админ-панели

```
$(function() {
        $('.order_form').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var s_data=$(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "ajax/order.php",
                data: s_data,
            success: function(data){
            if(data){
                $('#ajaxorder').html(data.ourl);
                $('.message_error').show().html(data);
            }
            }
            });
        });
    });
```

ajax/order.php

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

    chdir('..');
    require_once('api/Simpla.php');
    $simpla = new Simpla();

        $ourl = $simpla->request->post('ourl');
        $simpla->design->assign('ourl', $ourl);

        $dabla = $simpla->orders->get_orders(array('url' => $ourl));
        $simpla->design->assign('dabla', $dabla);

    if ($simpla->request->method('post') && $simpla->request->post('ourl'))
    {
        if($dabla)
        {
            $result = array('ourl'=> $simpla->design->fetch('ajax_order.tpl'));
            header("Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");
            header("Pragma: no-cache");
            header("Expires: -1");      
            print json_encode($result);
        }
        else
        {
            $result2 = ('<span>Заказа с таким номером нет</span>');
            print ($result2);
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Ну так откройте консоль разработчика и посмотрите в чём ошибка

Comment: Там на полсекунды выскакивает 500 ошибка и исчезает

Comment: во вклвдке network? можно посмотреть все xhr запросы, это аякс

Comment: А указанные пути точно относительные должны быть?

Comment: Я не знаю, друг попросил разобраться, а в ajax я не разбираюсь. Как мне показать xhr запросы?

Comment: sleep(1) добавте

Comment: Куда это добавить и зачем?